# .NET RabbitMQ Client and Not Acknowledged Messages

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, message-queue

Using the RabbitMQ .NET API, I am unable to receive a BasicNacks event. I can successfully BasicPublish a message to an exchange (any kind) and retrieve it using BasicGet or BasicConsume; however, if I then send a BasicNack using the delivery tag, the BasickNacks event does not fire.
I am registering an handler to the BasicNacks event before creating the exchange and queue, binding, etc, and I am doing a ConfirmSelect.
What could be the cause for this? What are the requirements or what is the common workflow for BasicNacking a message and having it return to the queue (enqueue = true)?

Answer (score 1):

You should send and listen for BasicAck event. Broker will send negative acknowledgement (Basic**N**ack) in exceptional cases when it unable to handle a message. See [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html)

Comment: So how can I return a message to a queue?

Comment: So your question is how consumer can give up on message processing? In this case consumer should send basic cancel. See here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-cancel.html

Comment: Not exactly. Here is the situation: a message is pulled from a queue, not acknowledged (?) and processed, what can take some time. Depending on the result of this processing, I may want to either remove it from the queue or return it to where it was. Does this make sense?

Comment: I think I got it. You were right about basic.nack. But it appeared that basic.nack is RabbitMQ extension to AMQP protocol specification. AMQP cpecifies only basic.reject command wich is what you are looking for. Difference between basic.nack and basic.reject is that reject works only for one message, whily nack can be used in bulk. See example here: http://www.rabbitmq.com/nack.html. It's possible to return message to queue or just ask broker to reject it.

In this case broker should not send nack event to publisher because it's not publishers business whether or not message processed.

Comment: If you need notify publisher about message rejection you shoul do it using another queue (And for this queue publisher and consumer will switch their roles). Does this help?